# Facebook API Errors list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the list of errors that are sampled at the Facebook Analytics for Apps?

As you can see in the image we only have the collective data for

```
GET /schema
```

[image]

In order to reduce the error rate I need the exact calls made.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.  Error analytics is one area I think Facebook could greatly improve upon.